# Noscript disable anchor tag behavior

Tags: javascript

When I disable javascript on my site, I want to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag.

```
<li class="last"><a href="#" id="viewexample" class="btn btn-view">View<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
```

How can I prevent this link from jumping to the top of the page when javascript is disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `<a>` tag at all, given it is not a real link?
You could change it into a button or add events directly to the `<li>`s.

Answer (score 1):

1. Drop the href attribute
2. Use css to add the 'pointer' cursor
3. Use js to add the desired behaviour to the anchor (so when js is disabled, the clicking will not do anything)

html & js:

`<a onclick="document.location.href='#'">View<span>&nbsp;</span></a>`

css:

```
a:hover {cursor:pointer;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the help of Javascript, since the href is pointing to #, you can't prevent it from jumping. You would have to change the # to an actual link.

Comment: I was thinking of disabling the button as default then enable it using javascript if it is on.  I realized there is no disabled attribute.. is there possibly a workaround using this idea?

Comment: There is a disabled attribute available for just about every form elements and a readonly attribute for input and textareas. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#noop">Link</a> <!-- #noop does not exist -->
```